# Get generic type class in superclass with GWT

Tags: java, gwt, generics

I have a GWT client generic super-class `SuperClass<T>`. There are sub-classes that explicitly define the generic type, like `SubClass extends SuperClass<String>` and etc. I need to get generic class type in super-class, something like `T.class` (of course it doesn't work, but I hope you get the idea).

So I ended up creating a method `Class<T> getClassType()` in super-class. In sub-classes I override it to the following:

```
@Override    
protected Class<String> getClassType(){    
 return String.class;    
}
```

While it works I don't like this approach as I have to explicitly define the type multiple times. I'm looking for some workaround so I can write less code is sub-classes.

On server-side I could use reflection, but on client side it is unavailable.

I saw some advices on using generators but don't really see how it can help here.

Answer (score 0):

I would pass it through the constructor:

```
public class SuperClass<T> {

    private Class<T> type;

    public SuperClass (Class<T> type) {
        this.type= type;
    }

    public void Class<T> getClassType() {
        return type;
    }
}
```

There are third party libraries for this:
https://github.com/jhalterman/typetools

There is no other way to get it in the *runtime* because **java generics** are a *compile time* feature.

Comment: Okay. While your solution ensures that the type will be defined, I'm still looking for some more elegant way. Too bad if these are the only options.

Comment: Don't know about one without third party libraries. And I also don't know any third party library for this, even tho they might exist.

Comment: I checked it and it seems to use java.lang.reflect inside which, as I told, is unavailable in GWT client-side.